# Tools to make shell work productive

Tags: bash

In our shell day by day work we have some tools/methods that make our work on shell a more productive.

Here a short list of such things I use in a day by day base:

- Ctrl+R to search interactive hrough bash history
- bash [auto completion](http://www.caliban.org/bash/#completion_download). This helps me to complete with Tab makefile targets, man pages etc.
- [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) to make directory navigation faster
- [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) to colorize the terminal output of GCC so error messages can be found within longer compiler outputs.
- [GNU screen](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935) can be helpful sometimes too

Recently I recalled my old friend [autoexpect](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1865), which "remembers" what  command you executed and what you entered. I use it "automate" scp commands for example.

Please share your tools.

Comment: This should be wiki, it's not a question.

Comment: This seems way too broad to me. Shells were designed to be the entire interface to a computer, and the number of methods and tools for use with them is correspondingly enormous.

Comment: @unwind: Even community wiki questions are meant to still be questions - and it's precisely for that reason that they can no longer be created directly by normal users. See [meta on community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Don't find where I can mark the question as wiki

Comment: @dimba: That's because you can't. Community wiki is not an excuse for non-questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn work effectively with Unix CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311656/how-to-learn-work-effectively-with-unix-cli) and others.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, it is kind of a question, the guy is asking for us to share our knowledge.

I use/like a lot of the tools you've mentioned.  I definitely like having a color coded shell, but some of the more productivity inducing things I use are thoughtful aliases in my .bashrc.  I have one for scptgz which, because I'm lazy, I don't actually have to tarball anything before I blast it off over scp.  Also I alias all my common ssh hosts.  Finally on our systems I have an alias sql='mysql --i-am-a-dummy -u user -p'.  Let's be honest, people do an update without a where clause sometimes.

Comment: When I say "not a question" I don't mean "it doesn't end in a question mark". I mean that it can't be reasonably *answered*. The best possible answer for this question would be a list of thousands of tips. That's not what we're really looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

I work a lot with git so my PS1 is showing me its status - [my git prompt](http://niczsoft.com/2010/05/my-git-prompt/)